# create my own nodejs web server on linux

Tags: node.js, linux, webserver, web-hosting

I just want to setup a nodejs webserver host on linux. It will be for development purposes only. I just want something I can simply setup on my own PC, Aspire XC 704G x64. Connect to my home network but also be able connect to it from anywhere online.

I can setup nodejs on linux with no problems as I already have one locally. But I am having issues trying to set it up so I can access it online. Is there any references books/tutorials whatever I can find step by step instructions. Or does anyone know where I can buy a computer/server already configured or some kind preloaded installation software I can get!

Thank all!

Comment: My guess is that you have issues accessing the server from another machine. What I did in that case when I was programming a server for a game of mine, I had to add a `port forwarding` to that server, because I was using a router. If you're not using a router, I know that you choose the host of the server as either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, or your actual IP which is accessible from outside. You should check if you have the option to set the `host ip`.

Comment: I have Time Warner with an Arris Internet/Phone Router. Thanks I'll look at port forwarding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is port forwarding. See https://portforward.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Docker on your machine. Its very lightweight and will do exactly what you described. No need for Virtual Machines, just start the docker container when you want to use the nodeJS environment, and stop it when you are done... takes a second to start and stop.

[Official Docker NodeJS image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)

You will enjoy Docker.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it